# 919B | nth Numbers having digit sum as 10 | Codeforces

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Here is the link to the [question](https://codeforces.com/contest/919/problem/B). Essentially, it asks to find the `kth` number having digit sum as 10. I have tried multiple solutions and also looked upon solutions online. Specifically this [one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n-th-number-whose-sum-of-digits-is-ten/) (also shared below). The one with constant time talks about outliers in Arithmetic Progression and uses it to find the `nth` number having sum as 10. Obviously, the code is incorrect as it fails for test cases when `k=1000` etc.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std; 

int findNth(int n) 
{ 
    int nthElement = 19 + (n - 1) * 9; 
    int outliersCount = (int)log10(nthElement) - 1; 

    // find the nth perfect number 
    nthElement += 9 * outliersCount; 
    return nthElement; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    cout << findNth(5) << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Eventually, I ended up writing combination of Arithmetic Progression + brute force as below

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll unsigned long long


int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int count = 0;
    ll i = 19;
    for (; ; i += 9) {
        int curr = i;
        int localSum = 0;

        while (curr) {
            localSum += curr%10;
            curr /= 10;
        }

        if (localSum == 10) {
            count += 1;
        }

        if (count == n) {
            break;
        } 
    }
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering, if there is no constant time or better algorithm that does not require me to calculate the sum, but my algorithm always hops in a way that I have number whose digit sum is 10?

Comment: What is "AP"? Contrary to popular belief, not everyone knows what these abbreviations mean.

Comment: Arithmetic progression. I will edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Python solution that you can translate into C++.

```
cached_count_ds_l = {}
def count_digit_sum_length (s, l):
    k = (s, l)
    if k not in cached_count_ds_l:
        if l < 2:
            if s == 0:
                return 1
            elif l == 1 and s < 10:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            ans = 0
            for i in range(min(10, s+1)):
                ans += count_digit_sum_length(s-i, l-1)
            cached_count_ds_l[k] = ans
    return cached_count_ds_l[k]

def nth_of_sum (s, n):
    l = 0
    while count_digit_sum_length(s, l) < n:
        l += 1
    digits = []

    while 0 < l:
        for i in range(10):
            if count_digit_sum_length(s-i, l-1) < n:
                n -= count_digit_sum_length(s-i, l-1)
            else:
                digits.append(str(i))
                s -= i
                l -= 1
                break
    return int("".join(digits))

print(nth_of_sum(10, 1000))
```

The idea is to use dynamic programming to find how many numbers there are of a given maximum length with a given digit sum.  And then to use that to cross off whole blocks of numbers on the way to finding the right one.

The main logic goes like this:

```
0 numbers of length 0 sum to 10
  - need longer
0 numbers of length 1 sum to 10
  - need longer
9 numbers of length 2 sum to 10
  - need longer
63 numbers of length 3 sum to 10
  - need longer
282 numbers of length 4 sum to 10
  - need longer
996 numbers of length 5 sum to 10
  - need longer
2997 numbers of length 6 sum to 10
  - answer has length 6

Looking for 1000th number of length 6 that sums to 10
  - 996 with a leading 0 sum to 10
    - Need the 4th past 99999
  - 715 with a leading 1 sum to 10
    - Have a leading 1
Looking for 4th number of length 5 that sums to 9
  - 495 with a leading 0 sum to 9
    - Have a leading 10
Looking for 4th number of length 4 that sums to 9
  - 220 with a leading 0 sum to 9
    - Have a leading 100
Looking for 4th number of length 3 that sums to 9
  - 55 with a leading 0 sum to 9
    - Have a leading 1000
Looking for 4th number of length 2 that sums to 9
  - 1 with a leading 0 sum to 9
    - Need the 3rd past 9
  - 1 with a leading 1 sum to 9
    - Need the 2nd past 19
  - 1 with a leading 2 sum to 9
    - Need the 1st past 29
  - 1 with a leading 3 sum to 9
    - Have a leading 10003
```

Looking for 1st number of length 1 that sums to 6
      - 0 with a leading 0 sum to 6
        - Need the 1st past 0
      - 0 with a leading 1 sum to 6
        - Need the 1st past 1
      - 0 with a leading 2 sum to 6
        - Need the 1st past 2
      - 0 with a leading 3 sum to 6
        - Need the 1st past 3
      - 0 with a leading 4 sum to 6
        - Need the 1st past 4
      - 0 with a leading 5 sum to 6
        - Need the 1st past 5
      - 1 with a leading 6 sum to 6
        - Have a leading 100036

And it finishes in a fraction of a second.

Incidentally the million'th is 20111220000010, the billionth is 10111000000002000000010000002100, and the trillionth is 10000000100000100000100000000000001000000000000100000000010110001000.

Comment: Thank-you for the help. I could not have imagined it to be a DP question.